# Moving contacts and messages from Windows Phone 8.1 to Android

Tags: data-transfer

I currently have a Nokia Lumia 520 running Windows Phone 8.1. I am migrating to an LG G3. How would I move my contacts and messages (texts) from one phone to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just save them to the SIM card, that *should* work.

Tap the menu icon, and a button should be labelled 'back up contacts'. Tqp that, and then tap 'SIM card'. It should save all your contacts to the SIM card. Then just put it in you new phone, head to contacts, tap the menu button, qnd press 'restore' and choose 'SIM card'. Then, choose the save point of your choice (to phone, SIM, or an added email)

Text messages are a bit more troubling, I'll look into it.

-EDIT-

I have found a similar request [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-can-i-export-or-extract-my-text-messages-to-a-file) from a while back, on the windows phone stack exchange. It will contain all you need. From there. Move the sdcard to your android phone, and install this app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Drestore+contacts+and+text+messages&pcampaignid=APPU_1_05uqVd2qIfKV7Ab5jqC4Bw) (assuming you have one, use PC otherwise) and just navigate to the sdcard (keep using the up a directory button, or up button in the app until you see either `sdcard` if your default storage is called emulated, or `extsdcard` if it is called sdcard) and choose the file to restore. It can do contacts, messages, and more.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how Gaurav would accomplish that?

Comment: I have only just logged back on, sorry. I'll add the info now.

Answer (score 1):

1. a. You (should be able to) export your contacts from your Windows Phone to a .csv file and import that into your Google account Contacts which can be accessed here: https://contacts.google.com

   b. Another way of doing the above is presented here: https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/i-have-saved-a-csv-file-from-my-old-phone-now-i-want-to-import-those-contacts-i
2. a. Once you import them into your Google account, then register your new Android device with your Google account and all your contacts should sync as well.

   b. If however, you wish to avoid registering the Android phone with your Google account, then move the .csv file you saved earlier (from your Windows Phone) on to the storage of the Android phone and select the import option from the default Contacts application.

I'm sorry I could not be more precise as I don't own a Windows Phone and the options for Contacts applications on Android changes according to manufacturers.

- Options for exporting and importing contacts files (.csv) should be present in the menus of the respective Contacts/People applications.